# Authentication with React, React-Redux-Router and Passport.js

Tags: reactjs, passport.js, redux, passport-local, react-router-redux

I am using Express for backend and passport-local for user authentication. The state has a user object with 'isAuthenticated' field to check if the user is authenticated.  After the user clicks the login button, I dispatch login action, which sends a post request to the server that handles authentication logic and sets 'isAuthenticated' to true. If the user is logged in, react-redux-router dispatches 'push' to change the location.

None of this seems to work however. When I click the login button, the page simply reloads. I see the actions dispatched for a brief second from the logger middleware but the whole app just reloads. Is there a way to get this to work?

Also, I saw an example that uses server side render to save the state so that when the page refreshes, the 'isAuthenticated' still remains true. Is it possible to achieve the same without using this method or cookies? Would there be a way to get the 'req.isAuthenticated' to the client side similar the how templating engines pass objects from the server side to the client side?

**Edit: So passport.js works fine on chrome apparently not Safari but I am still wondering what would be the best way to deal with the second question.**

Comment: Without code it's not gonna be easy to understand what's wrong... If you react application refreshes, you did something that make that! Did you prevent default the event from the login form?

Comment: Yes I did. It works fine now for some reason. Weird. What do you think would be ideal for for handling the second part though? Handling the cookies/session on the client or the server side?

Comment: It sounds like button could be submitting the form. Be sure to explicitly provide attribute type="button". Some browsers default to "submit" when no type is provided.